# How to listen for Room events

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

So to clarify, I know the client should send a message such as 'join-room' to the server for handling, and thats fine, and I know I can do the same for 'leave-room'.

What I want is to actually listen to the events themself, because say if a client disconnects, I need to send a message to the rooms affected, as when a client disconnects then they automatically leave all rooms.

So I want something like;

```
socket.on('join' function() {
// send message
});

socket.on('leave' function() {
// send message
});
```

So that if the user closes the window (which disconnects the client, and then triggers all the rooms to be left) I can send a message out.

I am using the latest socket.io, with the redis adaptor.

Also;

What is the most efficient way to list all the rooms a particular socket is in, as technically I think the disconnect event should contain the client_id so I could do this manually.

The key thing is clarity and stability, although I am open to alternate approaches (must still use socket.io).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understood correctly your main question: you want to listen to the events of joining and leaving a room in the implementation itself such that
`socket.join(room_id)` should fire that event you want to listen to.

The thing is the docs dont mention any ways of listening to that event. In fact, [the implementation itself](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L223) shows no sign of firing an event when joining a room. My guess is that you will have to implement the `join_room/leave_room` system to handle that.

As for the sub-question, the socket object contains an array called `rooms` such that `socket.rooms` contains all the rooms the socket is currently in.

This is probably what you're looking for :

`socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    for(var room in socket.rooms) { 
        //do stuff before the client close the connection and leave the rooms
    }
});`

Comment: Many thanks for the answer to the sub-question. I will need to investigate the event system further I guess.